# recyclerView creating all previews before being able to scroll below api 21

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm having a very strange problem, and this has been happening for all my `RecyclerView`s in API below 21, at the moment I'm trying with API 19.
The bug is that presently before `Recyclerview` is scrolled it "creates" all views before giving me control over it, so `recyclerView` appears with the first two items on the screen, and I can not scroll until `recyclerView` has "created" all Views, I suppose that it creates all the views, as I added a Log, on the `onBindViewHolder`.

Starting `RecyclerView`'s `onCreate()`:

```
recyclerViewExibirPosts = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.listViewExibirPosts);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
recyclerViewExibirPosts.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerViewExibirPosts.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

My XML: http://pastebin.com/HdtVVCJN

Comment: I'll take a guess and say you tried putting the recyclerview inside a ScrollView or another List/Recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

Create the RecyclerView like this and you should hopefully be good:
https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

The only way I think that it would ever create all views is if you literally forced it to somehow, but if you created all views in the xml layout or are somehow forcing views in code then that would explain it to me anyway.

RecyclerView should only create the first few or so based on how many fit on the screen then create more during scrolling.

(I have RecyclerViews based on the above that work fine and have been working fine with API 14+).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to apologize to the community, I found the bug, I was using a CountDownTimer to check when the information was retrieved, when I retrieved it, I canceled countDownTimer and called the method of inserting the data in RecyclerView, but the countDownTimer was not being canceled, so the method of inserting data into the recyclerView was called constantly until the onFinish time happens. I apologize for my lack of attention and thank you for your attention.